# Spring boot security using rest for login

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring security to manage users' authentication, i did it using `AuthenticationProvider` and by using Thymleaf `th:action="@{/login}"` and it works good but when i try to use postman for login as rest client `localhost:8383/login`it doesn't work

what i tried :

- by Coping the CUrl from the browser and add it to postman.

  `curl 'http://192.168.208.9:8383/login' -H 'Host: 192.168.208.9:8383' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Referer: http://192.168.208.9:8383/login' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=ECEB101AEB52EDF7409F6E249249D621' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data 'username=alice&password=blockchain'`.
- By create it manually.

The question is how do i login by rest calling?

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me. Did you mean that you need to return an authenticated JSON object(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) after you enter that URL in postman client ?

Comment: What i need is how could i use rest call to authenticate without using login ui when i use spring security.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at OAuth2 ? Here are some examples that can help you :

http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs

http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/